# Android Studio Java ANR Memory Leak

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks, realm

Thank you for watching and sorry for my poor English.
My game app faced with a problem.

sorce code
https://github.com/SpicyIslandFruits/TreeIslandPrototype2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/minor/prototype10

Why does my application crashes after playing a short time.
Logcat said

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) , code 1, fault addr 0x3f80001 in tid 27175
>   (RenderThread)

I don't know what it means...
This error occors while I'm in MainActivity, BattleActivity and StatusActivity
I think SuperWeapon.Java and SuperEnemy.Java and AbnormalStates.Java matters too...
Please someone teach me what's wrong and how to fix it.
I guess it is due to Realm.

And I'd be grateful if you tell me some improvements in my code.

Comment: share your **code,logcat**

Comment: @NavneetKrishna Could you tell me how can I get logcat...? Sorce is on my Github TreeIslandPrototype2.

Comment: https://github.com/SpicyIslandFruits/TreeIslandPrototype2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/minor/prototype10

Comment: There is a good chance that this is the known problem with libskia that if you have a RealmChangeListener that updates a view that is candidate for being destroyed, then libskia matrix can be `null` when update happens. Solution is to remove `RealmChangeListener`s in `onDestroy()` from managed RealmResults/RealmObjects.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It's solved!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you remove realm listeners in `onDestroy`.

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
    }
}
```